# How to get row count when use group in BIRT

Tags: birt, actuate

I have a table which has group and group related item .
i need to count all rows which include all group and all group related item.
Any comment is welcome !!
Thanks

Comment: You want count both grouping header rows and generated rows?

Comment: Is there some reason you can not use an 'Aggregation' item at the group (or whatever) level in the report?